# How can multiple processes run at the same if there is only one set of registers?

Tags: windows, assembly, operating-system, x86

I am currently learning x86 Assembly. Processes on a system can each use a portion of the available memory, and so each process cannot override each other memory. But there is only one set of registers on a system, so how can multiple processes run at the same time, I mean if `Process A` is using the `eax` register and so does `Process B`, wouldn't they override each other data? or does the operating system create some sort of "virtual registers" for each process?

Comment: Nothing *really* runs at the same time. :) http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching

Comment: It does on a system with more than one CPU core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The register contents are saved in on thread context-changes and restored for the new thread.  The register block is either saved on the stack of the interrupted thread or as part of 'Thread Control Block' kernel struct.

Answer (score 0):

Most processors have instructions for loading and saving the process context to such a memory block